# Get images out of product description in phtml file

Tags: php, html, magento

as the title might let you suggest I have trouble to get image URL's out of product descriptions in my custom phtml file (located in template folder).

In cms pages/blocks you can use

```
{{media url="wysywig/Banner/image.jpg"}}
```

which we do for parts (headlines) of our product descriptions.

Now when I try to display that description out of my phtml file with

```
<?php echo nl2br($productResult[$i]->getDescription()); ?>
```

the description gets loaded but the image URL's dont get converted to total
URL's like for example "/media/wysywig/banner".

I know that you have to use Mage::getUrl("media") in php/phtml files though this information doesn't help much in my situation.

The only idea I have is to set a string function to search for
    {{media url="wysywig/banner/image.jpg"}}
and replace it with
    Mage::getUrl("media/wysywig/image.jpg")
but I kinda feel like this isn't a very elegant solution.

Or is it the only way? Any help is appreciated.
Much thanks and greetings mpfmon

Comment: Try to filter your description string with this function before the echo: $description = Mage::getSingleton('widget/template_filter')->filter($description);

Comment: Yes! Big thanks it worked immediately. This is how I did it:
$description = Mage::getSingleton('widget/template_filter')->filter(nl2br($myProduct->getDescription()));

echo $description;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because it was not planned for the product description to have such media call:

```
{{media url="wysywig/Banner/image.jpg"}}
```

However there is nothing wrong doing this, to make it work, you have to filter your description with a widget function:

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('widget/template_filter')->filter($description);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable "Allow Dynamic Media URLs in Products and Categories" setting in Catalog section of Magento configuration screen. (See attached image)

[image]

Comment: This doesn't help when you want to get URLs within custom php files.
I did it as adrien54 said.
Thanks for the answer anyway.